# how to prettyprint a single-quoted JSON file using jq

Tags: json, jq, pretty-print, jsonlint

{ 'abc': { 'name': 'John', 'address': 'USA' }, 'xyz': { 'name': 'Robert', 'address': 'Canada' } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The sample is not valid JSON.
2. jq can be used to pretty-print valid JSON, though there are some important caveats, mainly about numbers.  For example:

   ```
   $ jq . <<< '{ "abc": { "name": "John", "address": "USA" }, "xyz": { "name": "Robert", "address": "Canada" } }'  
   {
     "abc": {
       "name": "John",
       "address": "USA"
     },
     "xyz": {
       "name": "Robert",
       "address": "Canada"
     }
   }
   ```
3. See the jq [FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) for information about converting not-quite-valid JSON to JSON -- search for `not-quite-valid`.
4. At least one of the tools mentioned in the above-referenced section in the jq FAQ (jsonlint) will not only convert single-quoted quasi-JSON to JSON, but also pretty-print it.
5. In the example you gave, you could use `sed` or even `tr` in conjunction with jq:

   ```
   echo "{ 'abc': { 'name': 'John', 'address': 'USA' }, 'xyz': { 'name': 'Robert', 'address': 'Canada' } }" |
     tr "'" '"' | jq .
   {
     "abc": {
       "name": "John",
       "address": "USA"
     },
     "xyz": {
       "name": "Robert",
       "address": "Canada"
     }
   }
   ```